# How to deploy war file to 12 jboss servers at a time through jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jboss

i have build a war file through jenkins by using maven. now i have to build that war file to 12 jboss servers after finish the build please help me how to achieve this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For multiple deployments, you better not use direct Jenkins features.
Instead you should use a configuration tool such as Ansible, Chef or Puppet.

Comment: is there any other way like deploy through shell.. please tell me

Comment: Ansible can be run from command line or Jenkins (that have also Ansible Jenkins plugin). 
Writing shell script that go over a list of 12 Jboss servers and run the same deployment for each server is possible but it seems like a bad practice since it is not handling all the aspects such as security, failures, run-in-parallel, logging and more - things that a configuration management tool is doing by definition.